# How to "dragenter" is not blocked by child elements?

Tags: javascript, html, css

https://jsfiddle.net/7scfk81L/

I have a document structure like this

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="inner"></div>
</div>
```

And i add `dragEnter` & `dragLeave` listener to container

But when I dragged into the file, it will trigger container `dragLeaver` and 'dragEnter' event when passing through the child element

Is there any way to make the parent element unblocked?

I tried add `pointer-events: none` to `inner`,
but that's not what I really want,
i hope that the child elements can be manipulated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well.. i solved by myself

Set a switch on a child element event, and the parent element filters events based on the switch

```
let isChildEntered

container.addEventListener('dragenter', (e) => {
    if (!isChildEntered) {
      console.log('dragenter')
  }
})

container.addEventListener('dragleave', (e) => {
  if (!isChildEntered) {
    console.log('dragleave')
  }
}, true)

inner.addEventListener('dragenter', e => {
    isChildEntered = true
})

inner.addEventListener('dragleave', e => {
    isChildEntered = false
})
```

[See demo](https://jsfiddle.net/3yk38z55/)